# update query with php mysql is not updating the database table entries

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'dbConfig.php';
$address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$pincode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pincode']);
$phone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactemail']);
$id=1;
$sql="UPDATE contactus SET address = '$address' , pincode = '$pincode' , phone = '$phone' , email = '$email' WEHER id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result)
{
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error());

}
```

it gives answer like this:-

```
DB initiated
Error:
```

What is the problem..?

Comment: WEHER is wrong it should be WHERE

Comment: You can use the built in mysql error function to get details if it was a query error http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: Misspelling should be encountered by the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` is spelt  incorrectly as `WEHER`:

Try this

```
$sql="UPDATE contactus SET address = '$address' , pincode = '$pincode' , phone = '$phone' , email = '$email' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a correct mysqli syntax.
here an example

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Persons SET Age=36
WHERE FirstName='Peter' AND LastName='Griffin'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

And fix you query

```
 WEHER id='$id'";
```

by

```
WHERE id='$id'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="UPDATE contactus SET address = '$address' , pincode = '$pincode' , phone = '$phone' , email = '$email' WEHER id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result)
{
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error());

}
```

should be

```
$sql="UPDATE contactus SET address = '$address' , pincode = '$pincode' , phone = '$phone' , email = '$email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result)
{
    die('Error: '. mysql_error());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the "link identifier" parameter in mysql_query function?

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

i know is not mandatory, but you are executing query with mysql_query, getting the error with mysqli, dbconfig we cannot see it.
So is difficult to guess.